# Как перевести char в формат unicode?

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть `char` в котором хранится число `62`:

```
char c = 62;
```

Я хочу вывести 62-ой символ в `unicode`. Если я сделаю `System.out.println(c);`, то увижу символ `>`.

Я знаю, что можно было задать c так: `char c = '\u0062'`. Но как быть если не я создаю переменную `c`, а она ко мне приходит в метод в качестве аргумента, например ?

Comment: Число в [unicode escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) - в 16ричной системе

Comment: 62 это '\u003e'. Вы путаете 10сс с 16сс, как уже сказал @zRrr

Comment: Если вам надо из `char c` получить номер символа в unicode (code point), то если `c` не является частью суррогатной пары, приведения к целому (`(int)c`) достаточно. Иначе нужно пользоваться методами класса `Character` `codePointAt` и т.п.

Comment: Вы рассматривали данное решение?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character